# Shipping icon in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code that displays an icon next to my transport. But it shows it at the end of the transport name. I'm puzzling a bit over how to move this icon directly after the input radio, and I still can't figure out how to do it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {      
   
   if( $method->id === "flat_rate:2" ) {
       $label .= '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/icon.png" />';

   }

   return $label; 
}
```

I've searched here on the forum but haven't found a concrete answer.
I would need your advice, please.

---

EDIT

Thanks @LoicTheAztec for the inspiration with your code. In the meantime I came up with a workable solution!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {      
   if( $method->id === "packetery_shipping_method:packetery_carrier_zpointcz" ) {
     (label)
     $icon = '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/primary.svg" />';
     $label = $icon . $label;
   }

   return $label; 
}
```

Comment: Did you tried: `$label = '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/icon.png" /> '.$label;`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it's not exactly what I want. But thanks to you, I've come up with a solution. Thanks, buddy!

Comment: @terahertz There is no obligation for an OP to answer his own question. Note that the OP is allowed to add an edit to his question, explaining what solved the problem.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You're right that it isn't obligated but [it is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions). Beside, it is confusing that [an answer is in a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387912/can-should-i-edit-my-question-to-an-add-answer) although it doesn't break any rules technically (afaik). For a newcomer, answering your own question allows you to gain some reputation, earn more privileges in time to come and better contribute to the site too, so why not? :)

Comment: @terahertz Because you use an authoritative tone instead of gently suggesting something to be done with some explanations. Now I agree that it should be better if the OP answers his question.

Answer (score 0):

generate a custom label structure with a  element wrapping the radio input, the original label text, and the icon.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_shipping_method_label', 10, 2 );

function custom_shipping_method_label( $label, $method ) {
    if ( $method->id === "flat_rate:2" ) {
        $input_id = 'shipping_method_' . esc_attr( $method->id );

        $label = '<label for="' . $input_id . '"><input type="radio" id="' . $input_id . '" name="shipping_method[' . $method->id . ']" value="' . esc_attr( $method->id ) . '"' . checked( $method->id, WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0], false ) . ' />' .
                 $label .
                 '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/icon.png" /></label>';
    }

    return $label;
}
```

Comment: This just duplicates my choice of transport method. It doesn't seem like the best solution.